# Make useMemo recalculate only when dependency changes to certain value, not on all of its changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In the code below, I want `successValue` to be recalculated only when the state changes to 'success', and not 'fail' or 'loading' or 'init'. Therefore, I am providing `state === success` as dependency to `useMemo`:

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

type Status = 'init' | 'loading' | 'fail' | 'success'

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<Status>('init')

  const successValue = useMemo(() => {
    if (state === 'success') {
      return 'success value'
    }
    return 'fallback value'
  }, [state === 'success'])

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setState('success'), 1000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Status: {state}</div>
      <div>Success value: {successValue}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setState('loading')}>Loading</button>
      <button onClick={() => setState('fail')}>Fail</button>
      <button onClick={() => setState('success')}>Success</button>
    </div>
  )
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is an [interactive demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bbnuf4?file=index.tsx): you will see that if you click 'fail' button for example, the `successValue` will change to `fallback value` - and I don't want that, I want it to stay as `success value`.

I think I misunderstood `useMemo` or how the dependencies work. Can someone provide and explanation and help me fix this?

Comment: Can you tell us _why_ you want to do this? I think you're indeed misunderstanding the point of `useMemo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `useMemo` alone will quite work for this use case because you want to recalculate it conditionally - but `useMemo`, if the dependency array changes, will unconditionally compute a new value.

Either store the prior value in state or a ref, then return that instead of returning `'fallback value'`, or do the calculation with `useState` / `useEffect` instead.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('init')
  const [successValue, setSuccessValue] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state === 'success') {
      setSuccessValue('success value');
    }
  }, [state === 'success']);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setState('success'), 1000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Status: {state}</div>
      <div>Success value: {successValue}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setState('loading')}>Loading</button>
      <button onClick={() => setState('fail')}>Fail</button>
      <button onClick={() => setState('success')}>Success</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Would be even better to name the expression `state === 'success'` with a variable, since that is often the convention for dependencies.